# How to manage Domain TXT record. What are limitations

Tags: dns, smtp, smtp-auth, domainservices, sendinblue

I am new to DNS management. I bought a domain from Godaddy. I've added some records like i've pointed domain to my cloudways server. Added TXT for google console verification. At the same time I added TXT Records to authenticate my domain to Email SMTP Service Provider (Sendinblue.com). Within 10 Minutes my records were propagated, google verification was sucessfull and my domain was pointed to my server. But TXT's for sendinblue.com were not being authorized. Now its been more then 2 days still didn't authorized. I dont know if there is something i did wrong in configuration. May be there are multiple TXT's of same type. As I mentioned above my domain is pointed to my server and google console is verified. If these 2 records were propagated then sendinblue should also be authorized at the same time. But still i waited for 2 days and no success. May be some issue in configuration.

Domain configurations screenshot( https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgP7O.jpg )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research i found a fix from a community. https://pk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/DNS-TXT-record-not-propagating/m-p/139411#M26840